# Repainting damaged acrylic coating on my shower tray. Help!

Tags: shower, painting, bathtub

I was cleaning something in the shower tray and I used a chemical which was petroleum based (which I didnt know), which caused the acrylic coating (I think its acrylic coating) dissolve.

I did a bit of research about repairing bathtubs/shower trays and it seems like nobody is able to achieve quality results by painting it, this usually involves using some kind of epoxy mixture, which cures for a very long time.

However, I have a different idea which nobody seems to be trying out... 
What I want to do is:

1. Use coarse sandpaper to the damaged area
2. Apply filler (what filer?) to level the work area
3. Use sandpaper again (medium)
4. Paint white (spray)
5. Apply acrylic clear coats (spray)
6. wet sandpaper medium>fine>extra fine
7. Buff it with a cutting compound to get the gloss on

**Questions:**

Is there any problems with my approach (if any)?

Is there a better way of doing it?

**Images of the damage:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why paint it, have you gotten a discoloration? Can you edit and post a picture of the damage?

Comment: My experience is that any attempts to repair/match color on a fix will exacerbate the issue and make it worse. If you have better luck, please be sure to share your solution.

Comment: Was this pan refinished before? It looks like a coat of something is on top of the factory gel coat

Comment: @Kris im not sure if it has. But you might be right there is a darker white underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any problems with my approach...?

- Use coarse sandpaper to **prepare** the damaged area- **GOOD**
- Apply **epoxy repair** filler to level the work area- **GOOD**
- Use sandpaper again (medium)- **GOOD**
- Paint white (spray)- **NO**
- Apply acrylic clear coats (spray)- **NO**
- wet sandpaper medium>fine>extra fine- **GOOD**
- Buff it with a cutting compound to get the gloss on- **NO**

Rather than using spray paint, use a 2-part brush-on epoxy paint specifically designed for wet service, [such as this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000PTSBKW). Repaint the whole shower pan. Note that this is fine for acrylic, but not for flexible plastic shower bases. This kind of coating can be made non-slip by adding an aggregate additive and can be tinted almost any color. And it is exremely tough/durable.

Comment: "Note that this is fine for acrylic...". Do you mean my method is fine for acrylic or the 2-part brush-on epoxy? Also, will the 2 part brush-on epoxy provide brand-new like finish? If not can I polish it in anyway to make it look like it?

Comment: @Marcin22 what is fine is what Jimmy is describing... not your plan.

Comment: Why wouldn't my plan work?

Comment: Yes, the 2-part epoxy paint results in a high gloss "like new" finish; **if** you follow directions exactly *and* use the best quality applicators. Spray paint is thin and nowhere near as durable (especially in wet conditions), but go ahead and give it a shot. you can always sand it off if it fails...